# How to observe photo library changes even when app is closed?

Tags: ios, swift, background-fetch, phphotolibrary

I need to be notified when a photo/video is taken, even when my app is closed.

Does anybody know how apps like Google Photos achieve this in iOS?

So far, I have implemented and registered PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver however photoLibraryDidChange only gets called if my app is in background mode but not if user manually closes the app.

**PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver implementation:**

```
import UIKit
import Photos

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    // ...

    var assetsFetchResult = PHFetchResult<PHAsset>()

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (authorizationStatus) in
            if (authorizationStatus == .authorized){

                assetsFetchResult = getAssets()!

                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
            }
        }
    }

    func getAssets() -> PHFetchResult<PHAsset>?{
        return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHFetchOptions())
    }

    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        print("photoLibraryDidChange")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let fetchResultChangeDetails = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: self.assetsFetchResult)

            guard (fetchResultChangeDetails) != nil else {
                return
            }

            self.assetsFetchResult = (fetchResultChangeDetails?.fetchResultAfterChanges)!

            let insertedObjects = fetchResultChangeDetails?.insertedObjects

            let changedObjects = fetchResultChangeDetails?.changedObjects

            let removedObjects = fetchResultChangeDetails?.removedObjects

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to achieve this through Background fetch.

First I enabled the background fetch capability in Project Settings > Capabilities > Background Modes.

Then I tested it by:

- Running the app from Xcode, then clicking on Debug > Simulate Background Fetch
- Duplicating my Scheme and enabling the 'Launch due to a background fetch event' option

However there seems to be no guarantees on when Background Fetch will be called on a real life scenario and I need it to be called as soon as possible after a photo/video is taken.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application

**Background fetch implementation:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //if application.backgroundRefreshStatus == .available && application.applicationState == .background {
        if let newData = getNewAssets() {
            newData.enumerateObjects { (object, _, _) in
                if let asset = object as? PHAsset {
                    // ...
                }
            }
            completionHandler(.newData)
            return
        }
    //}
    completionHandler(.noData)
}

func getNewAssets() -> PHFetchResult<PHAsset>?{
    let options = PHFetchOptions()

    if let lastAutoUpload = UserSession.getLastAutoUploadDate(){
        options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(modificationDate > %@)", lastAutoUpload as CVarArg)
    }
    return PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
}
```

Environment:
- Swift 4.2
- Xcode 10.1
- Testing on real devices: iPhone 6 and iPad Mini 3 (iOS 12)

Comment: I don't think so you can observe about change in Photo library when app is closed. But is possible then try to observe it when app is launch or comes in foreground from background. Hope this will work you.

Comment: simple answer it's not possible if app is closed

Comment: Persist timestamp when app was closed and retrieve any images created after that timestamp when app is opened.

Comment: have you find any solution about it?

Comment: Likely not possible given many passionate-professional apps don't do it, either. The most likely reason being they didn't figure out how