# How to run code in the background on iOS? Not sure which methodology makes sense

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession, background-task

I'm trying to set up background HTTP upload requests (syncing files from the user's phone to a server) that trigger periodically in my Swift app. I don't have strict requirements on when this runs (it can happen overnight or throughout the day).

I know Apple provides several APIs for background tasks on iOS (`beginBackgroundTask`, `BGAppRefreshTaskRequest`, `BGProcessingTaskRequest`, `URLSession` upload vs. background session). And I've seen [this post on the Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525) that attempts to explain the differences and when to use which - as well as [Apple's page on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing-background-strategies-for-your-app), but it's still not clear to me how a few of these work in practice, and thus which ones I should utilize for my use case.

My questions:

1. How should I schedule periodic file upload tasks in the *background*?

   - I assume I should use `BGProcessingTaskRequest`, since I don't know exactly how long the task will take (it could be syncing just 1-2 files, or it could be hundreds) and I don't care if it runs overnight
2. How should I ensure *foreground* tasks are able to complete after closing the app? (i.e. when a user starts a sync manually in the app)

   - [From Apple's page on `URLSessionUploadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionuploadtask#overview): "Unlike data tasks, you can use upload tasks to upload content in the background."

     - Does this mean any requests I make using `URLSession.shared.upload()` will automatically run in the background if the user closes the app? Even with the async/await version, or do I have to use the `completionHandler` version?
   - Do I need to call `beginBackgroundTask` if I'm using `URLSession.shared.upload()` to guarantee I get more time to finish uploads?
   - What about sequential requests (i.e. requests that haven't started yet by the time the app is closed)? Based on this SO response, it sounds like I may need to trigger all the uploads in parallel beforehand? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949607/2359478
3. Should I even consider [`URLSessionConfiguration.background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) for my use case? It sounds like it I use `beginBackgroundTask` and `BGProcessingTaskRequest` then this may be unnecessary?

Thanks!

Comment: Re point 3, `beginBackgroundTask` and `BGProcessingTaskRequest` only give you a finite amount of time (30 seconds and 5 minutes, respectively, last time I checked). So, if initiating large uploads (esp if “discretionary”, if you don’t want to chew up the user’s cell plan) a `URLSessionConfiguration.background` really necessary. Sure, a `BGTask` can be used if you want it to fire up periodically (at a time of the choosing of the OS) even when the user is not using the app, but if the assets are huge, only a `URLSessionConfiguration.background` will let you get around these time limitations.

Comment: Re “Does this mean any requests I make using URLSession.shared.upload() will automatically run in the background if the user closes the app?” … Nope, only the non-completion handler rendition of `uploadTask` in conjunction with a `URLSessionConfiguration.background` will achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is not possible to generate "periodic" (i.e. occurring at a specific interval) events of any kind in iOS that persist indefinitely. But it doesn't sounds like you need that. There is no need to sync data to the server when the user hasn't changed any data.

The use case you're describing is precisely what background transfers are  designed for. While they are generally discussed in terms of [downloading large files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background), the same technique is appropriate for uploads. Background uploads will continue to run in the background, even if your app is terminated. They are handled entirely by the OS, not your app.

In order for your upload tasks to continue running in the background, they need to be created on a background-capable URLSession. The default `.shared` session is not background-capable.

Similarly to how it is described in the background download docs, the steps are:

- Create a background URLSessionConfiguration using `.background(withIdentifier:)`.
- You probably want to set `.sessionSendsLaunchEvents` to false, so your app isn't re-launched when the upload completes.
- Setting `.isDiscretionary` is a judgement call. The way you've described it, you may want this option. But be careful if this is a syncing engine. It may be a very long time before the upload runs.
- With the configuration set, create a URLSession.
- Create a task with `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)`. You cannot use a completion handler or `async` version here. You can only upload a file from disk.
- You may want to set `earliestBeginDate` to delay the upload. This would make it easier to cancel uploads if there's a new version to sync before the upload starts.
- It is helpful to set `countOfBytesClientExpectsToSend` and `countOfBytesClientExpectsToReceive` to help the system schedule the task appropriately.
- Start it with `resume()`.

When your app is launched, you can recreate the session with the same identifier (this is often just a static string), and use `getTasksWithCompletionHandler` to get a list of all in-progress tasks. This will allow you to cancel uploads that haven't started yet if you want to make a new task.

You likely do not need `beginBackgroundTask` unless setting up for the sync takes non-trivial time. If so, then you could bracket that setup with a `beginBackgroundTask` and `endBackgroundTask` to help prevent it from being interrupted.

You also probably don't need BGProcessingTaskRequest. I would probably schedule all the sync operations while in the foreground. But if preparing for the sync is time or battery intensive, then it could make sense to push all of that work into a BGProcessingTaskRequest, and kick off the upload at the end. That is what they're for. But there's no need for it just to perform the upload. That's just the same as specifying `isDiscretionary`.

Whether you combine all of your uploads into a single file and create a single upload request, or create hundreds of small upload requests is up to you. Both have their benefits, and depend on how your sync engine works. The system is definitely capable of handling hundreds of requests without trouble. But I do recommend setting `taskDescription` to help you keep track of the tasks. It can even be used to encode useful data about the task. Its contents are entirely up to you. You should also be aware of use `taskIdentifier`, which will uniquely identify each task.

Comment: Thank you for this well-written response. The only issue is that the data I am syncing is photos data, so it won't be changing directly inside my app (it changes when a user takes a new photo or video). I'm assuming I'd use [`PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrarychangeobserver) in that case, in conjunction with the background `URLSession` approach above?

Comment: I don't believe you can [listen to PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver events while in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53538128/how-to-observe-photo-library-changes-even-when-app-is-closed), so a BGProcessingTaskRequest is likely the right tool to occasionally be allowed to synchronize.

Comment: “Background uploads will continue to run in the background, even if your app is terminated.” … Not if the app is force-quit, though. Just if it is suspended (and possibly jettisoned in the course of its normal life-cycle). +1